# I answered a duplicate and the answer got accepted: how do I clean up my mistake?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer, moderation

Question in context : [Excluding delete files from git diff-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59412360/10155936)

Sequence of Events:

- Mark the question as duplicate of this [Suppressing diffs for deleted files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692152/10155936)
- Find the answer specific to the question in context in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3692232/10155936)
- Immediately answer the question in context using the comment as reference
- Realize that my answer itself could be a comment
- Meanwhile the upvotes pour in...
- A user questions, what I am trying to do ? (marking duplicate and answering it at the same time)
- I proceed to delete my answer, and boom!! it is accepted
- OP of the question in context doesn't want to delete the question
- I flag my own answer for moderator review
- Update: Question was closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that's kind of a mess. :-(

But, moderator flags do work to clean up messes, as do Meta posts!

I've deleted the answer (which you couldn't do, since it was accepted). This also canceled any reputation changes, so you didn't lose anything from the downvotes but also didn't gain anything from the upvotes.

The question is rightfully closed as a duplicate, so there's nothing more to be done there.

And, of course, the asker has his answer, so one couldn't ask for any more than that.

Eventually, the question will be automatically cleaned up by a script (which we affectionately call the Roomba, after the robotic vacuum). For now, we'll leave it alone.

Comment: so we allow ourselves to delete answers of poor duplicates? or is it only because the person who answered asked for deletion?

Comment: @Jean-François Only because the answerer requested deletion. Answers that have been accepted cannot be deleted, but there are sometimes exceptional circumstances where these answers should be deleted anyway, despite the accept checkmark. A moderator flag is required for that case. I am generally willing to indulge such flags.